# An Issue with OpenCV extra modules

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, opencv-contrib

Because I couldn't compile a cpp code with using

```
#include  "opencv2/text.hpp
```

in `.cpp` file I noticed I probably have not linked and correctly set OpenCV libraries from extra modules.

Ok, so I tried instructions here [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib). I opened terminal and entered

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/user/openc/opencv_contrib/modules /home/user/openc/opencv
```

but I got a

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (message):
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

  OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

Could anybody please help me with setting OpenCV extra modules correctly?

I have tried CMake-gui but that have a lot more errors after processing configure.

Also I have tried force copy library module folder in `/usr/local/include/opencv2`, where basic modules are. But I got make errors with undefined references, for example like:

```
 undefined reference to `cv::text::computeNMChannels(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)' " ).
```

Comment: What OpenCV version are you trying to build?

Comment: Well I have istalled OpenCV version 3.4.1 (seen from headers).

Comment: Have you tried a clean build? Wondering if files from the previous build is causing errors while using making.

Comment: Well, I have tried to install openCV two times again to another folders to make sure for clean build and now I finally make it > Configured. Generated. But. Another Issues occured on the next step in 'make -j7' process. 
I typed it in a new topic here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558932/unable-to-complete-make-j7-with-opencv-contrib-modules