# unable to complete 'make -j7' with opencv_contrib modules

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake, opencv-contrib

Cmake can not compile extra modules from opencv_contrib. I am following theese [instructions](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) . Sorry for my length of my Ask, but giving more info about my Issues.
This is example of my CMake options:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/luke/cv/opencv_contrib/modules  ..
```

Till here it is fine. Configured. Generated  (maybe with basicly some warnings etc.) :

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/luke/cv/opencv-3.4.0/build
```

But when I enter in build directory "make -j7"

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  0%] Built target gen-pkgconfig
[  0%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/Half/half.cpp.o
```

...(**HERE will comes my ISSUES**)

then during a procedure, on the first module from opencv_contrib I will EVERYTIME get many of theese same couples of errors:

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_reg_pch_dephelp
[ 12%] Building CXX object modules/reg/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_reg_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_reg_pch_dephelp.cxx.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfStdIO.cpp.o

In file included from /home/luke/cv/opencv_contrib/modules/reg/perf/perf_precomp.hpp:56:0,
                 from /home/luke/cv/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/reg/opencv_perf_reg_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/home/luke/cv/opencv_contrib/modules/reg/include/opencv2/reg/mapperpyramid.hpp:64:114: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     CV_WRAP virtual cv::Ptr<Map> calculate(InputArray img1, InputArray img2, cv::Ptr<Map> init = cv::Ptr<Map>()) const CV_OVERRIDE;
                                                                                                                  ^
/home/luke/cv/opencv_contrib/modules/reg/include/opencv2/reg/mapperpyramid.hpp:64:120: error: ‘CV_OVERRIDE’ does not name a type
     CV_WRAP virtual cv::Ptr<Map> calculate(InputArray img1, InputArray img2, cv::Ptr<Map> init = cv::Ptr<Map>()) const CV_OVERRIDE;
                                                                                                                        ^
In file included from /home/luke/cv/opencv_contrib/modules/reg/perf/perf_precomp.hpp:56:0,
                 from /home/luke/cv/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/reg/opencv_perf_reg_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/home/luke/cv/opencv_contrib/modules/reg/include/opencv2/reg/mapperpyramid.hpp:66:35: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     CV_WRAP cv::Ptr<Map> getMap() const CV_OVERRIDE;
                                   ^
/home /luke/cv/opencv_contrib/modules/reg/include/opencv2/reg/mapperpyramid.hpp:66:41: error: ‘CV_OVERRIDE’ does not name a type
     CV_WRAP cv::Ptr<Map> getMap() const CV_OVERRIDE;
                                         ^
```

...

```
make[2]: *** [modules/reg/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_reg_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_reg_pch_dephelp.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/reg/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_reg_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This happens I think with each module from opencv_contrib. Ok but this type of syntax errors cannot be in each module..

I have **Ubuntu** version **14.04LTS** and I am using the last released **CMake version 3.12.0**. Tried older and tried also cmake-gui which version is about 2.8.
Does anybody know, what problem it could be ? :(
I have tried this several times and don´t know how to solve it.

**Just in my opinion:** it looks like there could be a problem with a compiler. I don't know maybe it doesn't have some key parameters like c++11 ?  But this should CMake make it with their 10 thousands of lines Makefile.. and with their gear. Or **Maybe wrong**(not good enouh) **GNU/GCC** version ?

I see I have in folder **/usr/bin/**
 file "**gcc-4.8**". I don´t know if I am using version 4.8 but I cannot see any else version "gcc-x.y" file in this folder.

Well,
[img1](https://ctrlv.cz/D2yD)

Maybe I could try something with changing make generator ?

But in cmake-gui I have only theese options: [img2](https://ctrlv.cz/Goan)

I also tried more versions of **OpenCV**. My last version I have tried now is **3.4.0**. (but also 3.4.1 and 3.4.2..) **Are there also more version of opencv_contrib modules?** I cannot find more versions. And this version of opencv_contrib seems to be 3.4.

Where do you think that problem could be? Any tips for solving this? I wanted to use these extra modules in my projects.

Comment: Try without -j Is it ok?

Comment: No, it isn't. I have tried it. Without '-j' it will work very slowly but after a long time it will cause the same result with errorss. So I think this just makes only some more threads (7threads together) to make that process faster.